# Query domain suffix from BigQuery table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get domain suffix from my table of websites, however, there is no reverse function in BigQuery and my domains have domains such as example.example.com. Thus, i cannot set the 1st2nd/3rd appearance of '.' as there is an inconsistent amount of '.'

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(Domain,( INSTR(Domain,'.')+1)) AS user_tld,
  COUNT(*) AS activity_count
FROM [table]
GROUP EACH BY
  user_tld
  HAVING
  user_tld IS NOT NULL AND NOT user_tld 
  IN ('')
  ORDER BY 
  user_tld DESC
  LIMIT 250;
```

This is where I am currently, only able to list out the whole domain name or the domain name after the first '.'

Answer (score 1):

1. BQ has some great URL functions: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?#urlfunctions
2. if this doesnt do the job, try to use regexp_extract instead of substring where you can define the exact string structure for your string and define it to match from the string end if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've already tried the Domain and TLD method. For the regexp_extract, i dont think it is viable for my current dataset as there are more than 100 different types of suffix.

Answer (score 0):

As [user2881671](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21108179/132438) says, you can use the TLD() function:

```
SELECT TLD('http://' + req_host), COUNT(*) c
FROM [httparchive:runs.2014_01_01_requests]
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1000

17130999    .com     
3106860     .net     
894779      .ru  
538917      .de  
504799      .org     
252716      .jp  
247244      .com.br  
225529      .fr  
218345      .pl  
206532      .co.uk
```

Note that TLD() is "smart enough" to recognize that the TLD is '.co.uk' instead of '.uk'.

If you want only the '.uk' part, regex are good too:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c, REGEXP_EXTRACT(req_host, r'(\.[^.:]*)\.?:?[0-9]*$')
FROM [httparchive:runs.2014_01_01_requests]
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 1000;

17130999    .com     
3106860     .net     
903360      .ru  
539167      .de  
504799      .org     
491532      .jp  
276205      .br  
258811      .cn  
237798      .pl  
230407      .fr
```